# scope only index action for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :superadmin do
    resources :tenants, only: [:index]
  end

  resources :tenants, except: [:index]
end
```

They produce the following paths:

```
tenants_path      | GET     | /superadmin/tenants(.:format) | tenants#index
                  | POST    | /tenants(.:format)            | tenants#create
new_tenant_path   | GET     | /tenants/new(.:format)        | tenants#new
edit_tenant_path  | GET     | /tenants/:id/edit(.:format)   | tenants#edit
tenant_path       | GET     | /tenants/:id(.:format)        | tenants#show
```

Expected behavior:

- `tenants#index` action is available at the route `localhost:3000/superadmin/tenants`
- all other `tenant` actions work via the regular routes `localhost:3000/tenants/*`

Actual behavior:

When I go to `tenants/new` and submit the form, thus activating the `tenants#create` action, I get the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/superadmin/tenants"):
```

I don't want to post to superadmin, I want to post just to the tenants_path. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the tenants#create action also uses tenants_path.

You should either change the path for tenants#index or for tenants#create.

The easiest thing to do would be to update your `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :superadmin, as: 'superadmin' do
    resources :tenants, only: [:index]
  end

  resources :tenants, except: [:index]
end
```

They produce the following paths:

```
superadmin_tenants_path | GET   | /superadmin/tenants(.:format) | tenants#index
tenants_path            | POST  | /tenants(.:format)            | tenants#create
new_tenant_path         | GET   | /tenants/new(.:format)        | tenants#new
edit_tenant_path        | GET   | /tenants/:id/edit(.:format)   | tenants#edit
tenant_path             | GET   | /tenants/:id(.:format)        | tenants#show
```

This way when you submit the form and proceed to the tenants#create action, it will not lead you to the superadmin path, and the form will work.